# Dropins Drobox plugin error

Tags: javascript, dropbox, dropbox-sdk-js

I have added this script on my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/2/dropins.js" id="dropboxjs" data-app-key="..."></script>
```

but in the console I always see this error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (HTTP/2.0 404) https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/2/dropins_sdk_v2.min.js.map
```

someone knows why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropbox doesn't serve a source map for dropins.js, so that message occurs when your browser requests one. It shouldn't impact the functionality of your page though.